# Avoiding 302 redirect when setting up multiple 404 pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-302

My error page is a PHP file, the entirety of which is

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$parts = explode('/', $path_parts['dirname']);
if (in_array("abcde", $parts))
{
    header('Location: https://example.com/vwxyz/abcde-error-page.php');
    exit();
}
else
{
    header('Location: https://example.com/vwxyz/error-404-page.php');    
    exit();
}
?>
```

I want users who go to a non-existent URL in the "abcde" directory to see a particular error page, and the URL should be https://example.com/vwxyz/abcde-error-page.php and the status code should be 302. This is working just fine.

I want users who go to any other non-existent URL (in the "vwxyz" directory, or anywhere else on example.com) to *see* https://example.com/vwxyz/error-404-page.php, but for a 404 status code to be returned, and the URL in their browser should still be whatever they erroneously typed in. Of course, that doesn't work with header('Location ... and I can't use file_get_contents or include because the result empties the shopping cart and logs out the user (if they were logged in).

I feel that there is a simpler way to *have multiple 404 pages* without editing the .htaccess file (though the argument will probably be made that that is indeed the simpler way). And it is vital that the main error page behave exactly like a normal error page, but that the other (for the "abcde" directory) be a redirect, and that that special error page for the "abcde" directory NOT be in that directory (the user gets redirected out of the directory and then shown the "error"page, which should NOT return a 404 status).

Comment: *"I feel that there is a simpler way to have multiple 404 pages without editing the .htaccess file (though the argument will probably be made that that is indeed the simpler way)."* ... yup, I'm pretty sure this would be 3 lines in .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly it *is* pretty simple via a root `.htaccess` file.

```
# enable mod_rewrite and route the request
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/abcde/?.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /vwxyz/abcde-error-page.php [R=302,L]

# sets a custom 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /vwxyz/error-404-page.php
```

First you need to switch the rewrite engine on, then perform 3 checks:

1. Does the URL begin with `/abcde/`
2. Is the URL **not** a file
3. Is the URL **not** a directory

If those things are all true then you want to route (with a 302) to `/vwxyz/abcde-error-page.php`

For any genuine 404 error you can just use the default `ErrorDocument 404 ...` syntax.

(OK this was 6 lines in .htaccess - twice as complicated as I guessed)

Comment: That did work perfectly; it seems that the real problem was really that I tend to try to do everything in PHP when often other methods are more suitable.